# how to enable Arabic language in ubuntu downloaded from ms store?

Tags: arabic

When I try to type a name of a folder in Arabic in the Ubuntu terminal downloaded with ms store (I am a windows user) it shows up as question marks... How to make it understand Arabic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install the Arabic language packs and set your locale accordingly:

1. Install the Arabic packages:

   ```
   sudo apt install language-pack-ar
   ```
2. Set the locale:

   ```
   sudo locale-gen ar_SA.UTF-8
   sudo update-locale LANG=ar_SA.UTF-8
   ```
3. (Optional) Install the Arabic manuals:

   ```
   sudo apt install manpages-ar manpages-ar-dev
   ```

This should give you what you need